# Sorting rows by count of a many-to-many associated record

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, associations, has-many-through

I know there are a lot of other SO entries that seem like this one, but I haven't found one that actually answers my question so hopefully one of you can either answer it or point me to another SO question that is related.

Basically, I have the following query that returns `Venue`s that have any `CheckIn`s that contain the searched `Keyword` ("foobar" in this example).

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.*
FROM "venues" v
  INNER JOIN "check_ins"   c  ON c."venue_id"     = v."id"
  INNER JOIN "keywordings" ks ON ks."check_in_id" = c."id"
  INNER JOIN "keywords"    k  ON ks."keyword_id"  = k."id"
WHERE (k."name" = 'foobar')
```

I want to `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` the count of the matched `Keyword` for each given `Venue`. E.g. if there have been 5 `CheckIn`s that have been created, associated with that `Keyword`, then there should be a returned column (called something like `keyword_count`) with the value `5` which is sorted.

Ideally this should be done without any queries in the `SELECT` clause, or preferably none at all.

I've been struggling with this for a while and my mind is just going blank (perhaps it's been too long a day) so some help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like:

```
SELECT v.x, v.y, count(*) AS keyword_count
FROM "venues" v
  INNER JOIN "check_ins"   c  ON c."venue_id"     = v."id"
  INNER JOIN "keywordings" ks ON ks."check_in_id" = c."id"
  INNER JOIN "keywords"    k  ON ks."keyword_id"  = k."id"
WHERE (k."name" = 'foobar')
GROUP BY v.x, v.y
ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: Oh man I was so close. I guess I was too tired last night. You, sir, are a hero!